# How to edit a particular column in csv file with unix command?

Tags: unix, csv

I want to write a script that will add new columns daily to a csv sheet.

The script will run daily and will append to csv file. Now how to edit csv file ? Edit will be via awk or sed commands. I will use this csv file to send mail to users and it will be used in excelsheets.

I have not found any relavent answers from all questions i have been through so please try to answer it .

Comment: Let's get clear on the meaning of edit.  Do you want to change the file using an actual editor (like vi or ed) programmatically, or change the file using tools like sed or awk?  The former is more involved.

Comment: via sed or awk. the script will run daily . It will capture some output from some other script and update the sheet according .

Comment: Doesn't adding columns ruin the structure of a CSV? Or do you mean adding rows?

Comment: No adding columns . I will store some test results. So initially the file will have only testcase names. Then everytime the script will run it will capture new results and update accordingly.

Comment: @rsplak - no, assuming some user will re-import the new file into excel or open office as a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$NF=$NF",new_stuff"}1' csv
```

```
$ cat csv 
1,shoes,red
2,apple,black
3,fog,blue
4,elephant,gray
5,monkey,green

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$NF=$NF",new_stuff"}1' csv 
1,shoes,red,new_stuff
2,apple,black,new_stuff
3,fog,blue,new_stuff
4,elephant,gray,new_stuff
5,monkey,green,new_stuff
```

Comment: partially correct , i think have to implement some sort of loop in new_stuff .

Comment: @AmarpreetSinghSaini If you can post some sample data in your question then may be we can work out a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

so you want something like that :

```
sed 's/\(john mayers.*\)$/\1\,hallo/' file
```

file:

```
john mayers ,hi   ,hello
jack bauer  ,yo   ,wasup
```

output:

```
john mayers ,hi   ,hello,hallo
jack bauer  ,yo   ,wasup
```

Comment: something like this but multiple rows will be present. say 50 rows and 3 columns everytime